# Center Image Vertically and Keep Same Height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is create a "cover" effect without using `background-url` directly in the CSS.

I would like the image to overflow and remain centered during mobile states, while the container height remains fixed at 600px. Is this possible while stilling using `img` tags?

Here's the [pen](https://codepen.io/zadro/pen/dyyagvy) with code below:

```
<header id="carouselHome" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active"><img src="https://placehold.it/1500x600" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="https://placehold.it/1500x600" /></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carouselHome" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carouselHome" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</header>
```

Corresponding CSS:

```
.carousel {}
.carousel-inner {}
.carousel-inner .item {
    height: 600px;
}
.carousel-inner .item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: maybe you can use `object-fit: cover;` https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Comment: That worked! I updated the Codepen.

Comment: Cool, glad that fixed it. Since it worked I will go ahead and add it as an answer. btw, I could not actually view your codepen because it is missing an href.

Comment: Sounds great. Here it is https://codepen.io/zadro/pen/dyyagvy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like css `object-fit: cover;` may work in this case. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Note that older version of IE don't support this property. This polyfill may be suitable for IE back to version 9. https://github.com/constancecchen/object-fit-polyfill

```
.carousel-inner .item img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You already said this above. If you add the full solution, I'll accept the answer.